# Many models, same manufacturer and the same question

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of switches and routers out there whose manuals doesn't specify whether or not they're supporting Jumbo Frames.

Searching for it on the web doesn't bring up any good answers so it's natural to ask a question at Super User.

Here are two questions about Jumbo Frames for two different router models from the same company.

- [Jumbo Frames on DIR-842](https://superuser.com/questions/1235900/jumbo-frames-on-dir-842)
- [Jumbo Frames on DIR-655](https://superuser.com/questions/197569/jumbo-frames-on-dir-655)

Is asking the question *Jumbo Frames on D-Link Routers* and then have a community answer better than having a separate question for each model? How will search engines treat that and will it be easy to find?

Comment: Why do we care how search engines will treat it?

Comment: So the answer is easy to find online.

Comment: Asking for (or maintaining) lists of *things* (whatever *things* are) is off-topic.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder So a question that will list the <insert amount here> routers that support Jumo Frames?  Sounds like a shopping list and that can be easily generated by anyone